# How do I get the name or id of the element ?? Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I get the name or id of the element to jquery

Comment: Do you have the reference to the element already? Or do you want the id to get the reference of the element? Your question seems to indicate the latter. In that case, you just need to assign an id in your HTML and use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to know the ID so can use it in the selector like `$('#the-ID')`? Either set it yourself if you can or look it up in the HTML source code.

Comment: Ok. I did. 
I wanted to get the name of the html element

Comment: Don't forget quotes around "#the-ID".

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the name/id from a selection

```
$().attr('name') 

$().attr('id')
```

or for selecting element(s)

```
$('*[name="somename"]')

$('#someid')
```